# Video onEnd triggers twice after re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, video, expo

I am using 
[React Native Video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video)
 component for my application. My component looks like this:

```
<Video
   source={{ uri: this.state.videoURL }}
   paused={this.state.isVideoPaused}
   onEnd={() => this.playNext()}
/>
```

and then my `playNext()` method looks like this:

```
playNext = () => {
    let playQueue = this.state.videoQueue;
    let nextElement = playQueue.pop();
    this.setState({
       videoURL: nextElement, 
       videoQueue: playQueue
    });
}
```

Everything works as expected, except for the fact that whenever `onEnd` event occurs, it triggers twice. And instead of playing the next video from the queue, the player plays the second video after the one which is supposed to be on.

Somehow during the first render of the next video `onEnd` is triggered again. I am assuming it has something to do with the current duration of the video which has not reset.

I am struggling with figuring out the correct solution to this problem. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I notice there is an old [pull request](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/pull/832) about this behavior on iOS. Perhaps the PR might shed some light. Are you experiencing this on iOS or Android?

Comment: @David784 I am encountering this on iOS running version 13.2. I do have the latest version of React Native Video as well so this change should be implemented in my version. I am actually not using the repeat attribute, but manually switching between sources of the video.